# why linked list wont print the first %s but only the second one

Tags: c, string, linked-list, char

i'm doing this project of linked list with 2 chars as their data that will be stored, but i runned into some issue regarding the display. i put both of the 2 %s as expected but it only printing the last one.

```
void print(NODE * tail){
    NODE *current = tail;
    if (tail != NULL) {
            do {
                current = current -> next;
                printf(" %s (%s) -> ", current->nama, current->jk);
            } while (current != tail); 
        }
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}
```

this is the full code of the linked list that i make

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node {
    char nama[20];
    char jk[1];
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node NODE;

NODE *buatnodebaru(char a[20], char b[1]){
    NODE * nodebaru = (NODE *) malloc (sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(nodebaru -> nama, a);
    strcpy (nodebaru -> jk , b);
    
    return nodebaru;
}

void print(NODE * tail){
    NODE *current = tail;
    if (tail != NULL) {
            do {
                current = current -> next;
                printf(" %s (%s) -> ", current->nama, current->jk);
            } while (current != tail); 
        }
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}

int panjang(NODE * tail) {
    NODE * current = tail;
    int i = 1;
    if (tail == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        current = current -> next;
        while (current != tail) {
            i++;
            current = current -> next;
        }
    }
    return i;   
}

NODE *insertawal(NODE * tail, char a[20], char b[1]) {
    NODE * nodebaru = buatnodebaru(a,b);
    if (tail == NULL) {
        tail = nodebaru;
        nodebaru -> next = nodebaru;
    } else {
        nodebaru -> next = tail -> next;
        tail -> next = nodebaru;
    }
    return tail;
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}

NODE * insertakhir(NODE * tail, char a[20], char b[1]) {
    return insertawal(tail, a, b) -> next;
}

NODE * insertsetelah(NODE * tail, char a[20], char b[1], int location) {
    int len = panjang(tail), i;
    if (location < 1 || location > len + 1) {
        printf("\nInvalid location to enter data\n");
    } else {
        if (tail == NULL) return insertawal(tail, a, b);
        NODE * nodebaru = buatnodebaru(a,b), * current = tail;
        for (i = 1; i != location; i++) current = current -> next;
        nodebaru -> next = current -> next;
        current -> next = nodebaru;
        if (location == len + 1) tail = nodebaru;
        print(tail);
    }
    return tail;
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}

NODE * deleteberdasarisi(NODE * tail, char a[20], char b[1]) {
    NODE * current = tail, * previous;
    if (tail == NULL) return tail;
    else if (tail == tail -> next) {
        if (tail -> nama == a && tail -> jk == b ) {
            tail = NULL;
            free(current);
        }
        return tail;
    } 
    do {
        previous = current;
        current = current -> next;
        if (current -> nama == a && current -> jk == b) {
            previous -> next = current -> next;
            if (current == tail) tail = previous;
            free(current);
            current = previous -> next;
        }
    } while (current != tail);
    return tail;
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}

NODE * deleteberdasarlokasi(NODE * tail, int location) {
    NODE * current, * previous = tail;
    int len = panjang(tail), i;
    if (location < 1 || location > len) {
        printf("Invalid Location to delete");
    } else if (len == 1) {
        tail = NULL;
        free(current);
    } else {
        current = tail -> next;
        for (i = 1; i < location; i++) {
            previous = current;
            current = current -> next;
        }
        previous -> next = current -> next;
        if (current == tail) tail = previous;
        free(current);
    }

    return tail;
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}

int main (){
    NODE * cll = NULL;
    int pilihan;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("        PROGRAM LINKED LIST\n");
        printf("    ================================\n");
        printf("    1. Memasukkan data di awal\n");
        printf("    2. Memasukkan data akhir (ekor) \n");
        printf("    3. Memasukkan data setelah \n ");
        printf("    4. Menghapus data berdasar isi\n");
        printf("    5. Menghapus data berdasar lokasi\n");
        printf("    6. Keluar\n");
        printf("    ================================\n");
        printf("    Masukkan Pilihan Anda : ");
        scanf("%d", &pilihan);
        if (pilihan==1)
        {
            char name[20];
            char gender[1];
            printf("\n  Masukkan nama : "); 
            scanf("%s", &name);
            printf("\n  Masukkan jk : ");   
            scanf("%s", &gender);
            cll = insertawal(cll, name, gender);
            print(cll);
        }
        else if (pilihan==2)
        {
            char name[20];
            char gender[1];
            printf("\n  Masukkan nama : "); 
            scanf("%s", &name);
            printf("\n  Masukkan jk : ");   
            scanf("%s", &gender);
            cll = insertakhir(cll, name, gender);
            print(cll);
        }
        else if (pilihan==3)
        {
            char name[20];
            char gender[1];
            int location;
            printf("\n  Masukkan nama : "); 
            scanf("%s", &name);
            printf("\n  Masukkan jk : ");   
            scanf("%s", &gender);
            cll = insertakhir(cll, name, gender);
            printf("\n  setelah elemen yang mana data akan dimasukkan : "); 
            scanf("%d", &location);
            cll = insertsetelah(cll, name, gender, location);
            print(cll); 
        }
        else if(pilihan==4)
        {
            char name[20];
            char gender[1];
            printf("\n  Masukkan nama : "); 
            scanf("%s", &name);
            printf("\n  Masukkan jk : ");   
            scanf("%s", &gender);
            cll = deleteberdasarisi(cll, name, gender);
            print(cll);
        }
        else if(pilihan==5)
        {
            int dell;
            printf("\n  Masukkan lokasi yang akan di delete : ");   
            scanf("%d", &dell);
            cll = deleteberdasarlokasi(cll, dell);
            print(cll);
        }
        else if(pilihan==6)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

it should be printing

```
name(g)->name(g)->
```

yet it's only printing

```
(g) -> (g) ->
```

what should I do?

i tried to check the string that i make, i cant seems to find the problem.

Comment: Note: any code in a function _after_ a `return` is unreachable and is never executed. See `system("pause");` and `system("CLS");` at the end of several of your functions.

Answer (score 1):

All these arrays:

```
char jk[1];
char gender[1];
...
```

have enough space for only one character. However you're trying to store the string `"g"` into them, which takes **TWO** chars: one for the 'g' and one for the null-terminator. This triggers undefined behavior per the standard; most likely the `name` array is laid out after `gender` on the stack, thus the `gender` null terminator gets written to the first char of the `name`, turning it into an empty string regardless of the user input.

Increase the size of all those arrays to, at least, two chars.

Comment: omg, thankyou so much, i didn't realize such small thing.